# Optimise and reduce redundancy in Flask routing

Tags: refactoring, flask, flask-security

I have a number of objects, `User`, `Role`, `Post`, `Category` and possibly more, and have a number of admin views that basically just display and handle forms associated with those objects. My current code looks like this:

```
admin = Blueprint('admin', __name__)

@login_required
@admin.route('/users')
def users():
  return list_object(User)

@roles_required('admin')
@admin.route('/users/new',  methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def create_user():
    return create_object(User, UserForm)

@roles_required('admin')
@admin.route('/users/delete/<int:user_id>',  methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def delete_user(user_id):
   return delete_object(User, user_id)

@roles_required('admin')
@admin.route('/users/<int:user_id>',  methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def edit_user(user_id):
    return edit_object(User, user_id, UserForm)

@login_required
@admin.route('/categories')
def categories():
  return list_object(Category)

@roles_accepted('admin', 'editor')
@admin.route('/categories/new',  methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def create_cat():
    return create_object(Category, CategoryForm)

@roles_accepted('admin', 'editor')
@admin.route('/categories/delete/<int:cat_id>',  methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def delete_cat(cat_id):
   return delete_object(Category, cat_id)

@roles_accepted('admin', 'editor')
@admin.route('/categories/<int:cat_id>',  methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def edit_cat(cat_id):
    return edit_object(Category, cat_id, CategoryForm)
```

And so on. `edit_object`, `list_object` &c are defined as well. My question is: how can I reduce the redundancy here? `@login_required` and `@roles_required` are provided by `flask-security`. How can I optimise this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have these sorts of identical setups you may want to look into the [Flask-Restless Extension](https://flask-restless.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).  If that doesn't quite suite your needs you can use Flask's [pluggable (class-based) views](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/views/):

```
from flask.views import View

LIST, NEW, EDIT, DELETE = "list", "new", "edit", "delete"
METHODS = (LIST, NEW, EDIT, DELETE)

class AbstractManager(View):
    DataClass = None
    Form = None

    methods = ["GET", "POST"]
    decorators = [login_required, create_roles_decorator_for("admin", "editor")]

    def dispatch_request(self, method=LIST, id=None):
        if not method in METHODS:
            abort(404)

        if method == LIST and id is not None:
            method = EDIT

        return getattr(self, method)(id)

    def list(self, id):
        if request.method != "GET":
            abort(405)
        return list_object(self.DataClass)

    def new(self, id):
        return create_object(self.DataClass, self.Form)

    def edit(self, id):
        return edit_object(self.DataClass, id, self.Form)

    def delete(self, id):
        return delete_object(self.DataClass, id)


class UserManager(AbstractManager):
    DataClass = User
    Form = UserForm


class CategoryManager(AbstractManager):
    DataClass = Category
    Form = CategoryForm
```

Alternately, you can [avoid writing stupid classes](http://me.veekun.com/blog/2013/03/03/the-controller-pattern-is-awful-and-other-oo-heresy/) and just use a function:

```
def register_api_for(DataClass, ClassForm, name=None, app=None):
    name = name if name is not None else DataClass.__name__.rsplit(".", 1)[1]
    base_route = "/" + name

    @login_required
    @app.route(base_route, endpoint="list_" + name)
    def list():
        return list_object(DataClass)

    # remaining implementation left as an exercise for the reader
```